# "unpack" std::array<T,N> as arguments to function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stdarray, stdtuple

Here is quite nice (not mine) example how u can expand (or "explode") tuple as arguments to function:

```
template<int ...I> struct index_tuple_type {
  template<int N> using append = index_tuple_type<I..., N>;
};

template<int N> struct make_index_impl {
  using type = typename make_index_impl<N-1>::type::template append<N-1>;
};

template<> struct make_index_impl<0> { using type = index_tuple_type<>; };

template<int N> using index_tuple = typename make_index_impl<N>::type;

template <typename I, typename ...Args>
struct func_traits;

template <typename R, int ...I, typename ...Args>
struct func_traits<R, index_tuple_type<I...>, Args...> {
  template <typename TT, typename FT>
  static inline R call(TT &&t, FT &&f) {
    return f(std::get<I>(std::forward<TT>(t))...);
  }
};

template<
  typename FT,
  typename ...Args, 
  typename R = typename std::result_of<FT(Args&&...)>::type
>
inline R explode(std::tuple<Args...>& t, FT &&f) {
  return func_traits<R, index_tuple<sizeof...(Args)>, Args...>
    ::call(t, std::forward<FT>(f));
}
```

then you can use this like so:

```
void test1(int i, char c) {
  printf("%d %c\n", i, c);
}

int main() {
  std::tuple<int, char> t1{57, 'a'};
  explode(t1, test1);
}
```

[Live version](http://ideone.com/abiKOo)

I was wandering how could you do the same thing with `std::array` since it quite like tuple. `std::get<N>` works with `std::array` so I thought that it would be easy to modify this solution. But something like this doesn't work:

```
template<
  typename FT,
  typename Arg,
  std::size_t I,
  typename R = typename std::result_of<FT(Arg&&)>::type
>
inline R explode(std::array<Arg, I>& t, FT &&f) {
  return func_traits<R, index_tuple<I>, Arg>::
    call(t, std::forward<FT>(f));
}

void test2(int i1, int i2) {
  printf("%d %d\n", i1, i2);
}

int main() {
  std::array<int, int> t1{1, 2};
  explode(t2, test1);
}
```

because of the part `std::result_of<FT(Arg&&)>::type`. The argument type `Arg&&` is wrong and `result_of` has no field `type`. For tuple `Args&&...` expanded, but now it should be "repeated" `I` times. Is there a way to do this using `result_of` so the returned type can be deducted?

Also i was wondering, having the tools to "unpack" `tuple` and `array` would it be possible to "unpack" recursively (probably using `enable_if`) structure like `tuple<array<int, 2>, tuple<array<double,3>, ...` and so on? Some kind of a tree where `tuple` and `array` are branches, and other types are leaves?

Comment: `std::forward` with an lvalue reference harcoded as a type template argument equals "no-op". and you probably meant to put `t` as its argument. and btw, use [trailing return type like here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5af1aac65ba014d9) instead

Comment: Have you considered instead making a function that coverts an array to a tuple of references?

Comment: @PiotrS. corrected that `forward`, my bad expanding macro the wrong way. @Hurkyl Yeah i thought about it but isn't this a bit way around.

Comment: @The_Ham it still won't work as you think. now `std::forward<std::tuple<Args...>>(t)` equals `std::move(t)` (unconditionally)

Comment: Flattening a bunch of `tuple`-likes into a single `tuple` is, in my opinion, a distinct question.  I answered your first question.

Comment: Since nobody mentioned, the proposed [apply](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/apply) can be used with `std::array` just like with `std::tuple`. [See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d114352e25ad96b).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
// enable argument dependent lookup on `get` call:
namespace aux {
  using std::get;
  template<size_t N, class T>
  auto adl_get( T&& )->decltype( get<N>(std::declval<T>()) );
}
using aux::adl_get;
template<class F, class TupleLike, size_t...Is>
auto explode( F&& f, TupleLike&& tup, std::index_sequence<Is...> )
-> std::result_of_t< F( decltype(adl_get<Is>(std::forward<TupleLike>(tup)))... ) >
{
  using std::get; // ADL support
  return std::forward<F>(f)( get<Is>(std::forward<TupleLike>(tup))... );
}
```

is the first step.  `std::index_sequence` is C++14, but it is easy to implement in C++11.

The next steps are also easy.

First, a traits class that dictates what types are tuple-like.  I would go ahead and just duck-type use them, but a number of functions and traits classes we are going to use are not SFINAE friendly:

```
template<class T>
struct tuple_like:std::false_type{};
template<class... Ts>
struct tuple_like<std::tuple<Ts...>>:std::true_type{};
template<class... Ts>
struct tuple_like<std::pair<Ts...>>:std::true_type{};
template<class T, size_t N>
struct tuple_like<std::array<T,N>>:std::true_type{};
```

Next, an overload of `explode` that only works on `tuple_like` types:

```
template<class F, class TupleLike,
  class TupleType=std::decay_t<TupleLike>, // helper type
  class=std::enable_if_t<tuple_like<TupleType>{}>> // SFINAE tuple_like test
auto explode( F&& f, TupleLike&& tup )
-> decltype(
  explode(
    std::declval<F>(),
    std::declval<TupleLike>(), 
    std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<TupleType>{}>{}
  )
)
{
   using indexes = std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<TupleType>{}>;
   return explode(
     std::forward<F>(f),
     std::forward<TupleLike>(tup),
     indexes{}
   );
}
```

If you lack `constexpr` support you need to change some `{}` to `::value` .

The above does the trick for pairs, arrays or tuples.  If you want to add support for other tuple-like types, simply add a specialization to `tuple_like` and ensure `std::tuple_size` is specialized properly for your type and `get<N>` is ADL-overloaded (in the type's enclosing namespace).

---

`std::make_index_sequence` is also C++14 but easy to write in C++11.

```
template<size_t...>
struct index_sequence{};
namespace details {
  template<size_t count, size_t...Is>
  struct mis_helper:mis_helper<count-1, count-1, Is...> {};
  template<size_t...Is>
  struct mis_helper<0,Is...> {
    using type=index_sequence<Is...>;
  };
}
template<size_t count>
using make_index_sequence=typename details::mis_helper<count>::type;
```

(this is poor QOI for a C++14 library, which should use at least log descent, as it requires O(n) template recursive template instantiations for a list of size n.  However, is n is less than a few 100, it won't matter).

`std::enable_if_t<?>` is C++14, but in C++11 is just `typename std::enable_if<?>::type`.

Comment: Why overload and not just take a `TupleLike` and use `tuple_size`?

Comment: @T.C. unspecified behavior when `tuple_size` is handed something that isn't a tuple/array/pair means that it doesn't do clean SFINAE.  And in my experience the use case for this kind of thing benefits from SFINAE.

Comment: @T.C. there.  SFINAE check for `tuple_like`ness, one forwarding `TupleType`.

Comment: @The_Ham no.  My comment below your question states you asked two questions: I answered one.  The problem of flattening a tuple-like type of possibly tuple-like contents is a different one than the problem of invoking a function with a tuple-like set of arguments.  On stack overflow, you should ask one question per post.  It is easy to compose (flatten tuples) with (invoke a function with tuples) and get (invoke a function with flattened tuples); but writing (invoke a function with flattened tuples) *directly* is a bad idea.

Comment: @The_Ham an approach that might work.  Create `struct tuple_flattener` that takes its arguments, and for each one they are tuples, does an `explode( tuple_flattener{}, arg )`, and those that are not it just does `arg`.  It then `make_tuple`s the results and returns it.  Now, call `explode( f, tuple_flattener{}(arg) )` to get your flattened explosion.  I think that will work.  (earlier version of this comment failed to recurse enough).  Deducing the return type remains tricky, you might have to do that independently rather than relying on `auto`.

Comment: @Yakk Sorry didn't read that comment in time. Thanks for help. May I ask where did you get the knowledge about this c++11 up meta-programming stuff. It gives me such a headache to make sens out of it, even more to write sth on my own.

Comment: @Yakk Hmm, why did I get pinged by your last comment?

Comment: @t.c dunno.  I sometimes get pinged without @ addresses?

Comment: @the_ham like anything, start simple, practice, internalize, abstract, build, correct.